# FTP or file share

Tags: ftp, port, cloud, share

I have a server hosted in a cloud running ubuntu server 15.10. I don't have access to all ports (only main ports) and I wanted to install some kind of FTP server or sharing server. I'd like to host a couple of big size files and the cloud server has high bandwith and it would avoid filling my bandwith.

The result I would like is the following: host big files using the big bandwith and give a simple link to my customers to download the files (avoiding if possible client software). Nice feature would also be pause\resume download.

Firstly I want to point out I can't change the providers firewall so I have access to limited ports, and only have ssh access to the server (no graphical interface). So I need something that can be command line managed. This can change if I pay more, but I would like to avoid unless necessary.

What I automatically discarded:

1. HTTP (apache or nginx) because it would also mean developing a minimum interface to give my collegues a way of uploading a file to make it available to customers. Plus apache or nginx configurations have a lot size\timeout limits which in time might need to be maintained.

This is what I have tried:

1. FTP works but not in passive mode (because of port restrictions) so it would mean installing a client software.
2. SFTP works but need client software.
3. Btsync: not in apt for ubuntu 15.10. Installed anyway but couldn't change port settings
4. syncthing: couldn't change port settings for web interface (default is 8384 I would need 80)

I am thinking allong the lines of becoming a private bittorrent server or something similar? Any ideas?

Thank you and best regards,
James

Comment: It sounds more like you need to learn to properly manage your own or your providers  firewall than anything else, or if it's really impossible to run the services you want, change provider...

Comment: I have better explained my question if you could please unhold it.

Comment: I personally still consider your question  [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com but by editing it your revised question will automatically be reviewed by the community who may decide differently. If they don't;  potentially your question can be reworded or is suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community

Answer (score 1):

A web server fills all your stated requirements, it can serve any file type you like to a web browser. Large file downloads over HTTP are no problem. Nginx or Apache would both work, Nginx is simpler and generally uses less resources.

I suspect you may have already considered this and discounted it. If so please update your question with more details.